WCF service throws error in ASP.NET MVC. Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority
First of all there is a ton of question with the same title but I believe my problem is little bit different from other questions. I would like to state that everything where perfectly fine about two days ago. I haven't changed anything in code.
We are not required to install any SSL certificate to our servers or local computers. The url of the WCF service opens normally on browser (https://sampleurl.com/service.svc)
I created a console application for testing purposes, it works but it doesn't work in our ASP.NET MVC 5 project.
How I call the service:
 CustomerServiceClient client = new CustomerServiceClient();
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test@asfasf.com";
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "asfasf";

 var result = client.GetInformation("1MS0274796");

The response is:

System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: 'Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'servis.vatanbilgisayar.com'.'
Inner Exception: WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

What I've tried
I added this line of code before the service call, but it didn't work:
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

and
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
    (se, cert, chain, sslerror) =>
        {
            return true;
        };

This addition to the code throws this error:

The certificate key algorithm is not supported

web.config:
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="CustomerServiceSoap">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://xyzx.com/CustomerService.svc"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  bindingConfiguration="CustomerServiceSoap"
                  contract="xfasf.asfasf" name="CustomerServiceSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>

Update:
It turns out you should call Open and Close methods in order to call service. After several calls without this practice, service might not respond at all. It is weird that never happened before and started spontaneously.

You did not show how you were binding to your endpoint ion code. You are using https?

Yes, I assume I am  using https. I added the service via Add Service Reference and called it like in the question. I am not very familiar with WCF services. Didn't quite catch what you are asking @RossBush

Does the inner exception itself have an inner exception? Best bet is to use something like Wireshark to watch for the Client and Server Hello packets, and try work out what's missing. Usually it's a TLS version or cipher or hash mismatch, or an unsigned or expired certificate. Don't set ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol that will make things worse.

You'll need a certificate, and you'll need to generate a validation class. I'll give you an example:
Service web.config:
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Service1Binding">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior" name="ConsoleApp6.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Service1Binding"
                  contract="ConsoleApp6.IService1">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="QiYouCert" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="......" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="QiYouCert" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" />
                        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="ConsoleApp6.CustomUserNameValidator,ConsoleApp6" />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Service Validation class:
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
 {

     public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
     {
         if (null == userName || null == password)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException();
         }
         if (userName != "admin" && password != "wcf.admin") 
         {
             throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Password");
         }

     }
 }

Client account and password verification:
 using (var proxy = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
 {
     proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "a22dmin";
     proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "w22cf.admin";
     string result = proxy.GetData(1);
     Console.WriteLine(result);
   
 }
 Console.ReadKey();

If the password account does not match, an error will be reported:

